# How to get all elements returned by a method include those defined from super class?

Tags: ios, arrays, inheritance

I'm currently writing a json <> model serializer. One of the feature is to ignore certain properties from the model when converting to json. I'm letting the model implement a `- (NSArray *)ignoreProperties` method to tell the serializer which properties it should ignore. Obviously it needs to support inheritance. But now i'm stuck with how to properly combine all the array elements from the object itself and all the super classes.

```
@protocol SerializerMapping <NSObject>
- (NSArray *)ignoreProperties;
@end

@interface BaseModel : NSObject <SerializerMapping>
@property NSString *baseProperty;
@end

@implementation BaseModel
- (NSArray *)ignoreProperties {
    return nil; // nothing to ignore
}
@end

// ---
@interface SuperModel : BaseModel
@property NSString *property1;
@property NSString *property2;
@end

@implementation SuperModel
- (NSArray *)ignoreProperties {
    return @[@"property1"];
}
@end

// ---
@interface AwesomeModel : SuperModel
@property NSString *property3;
@property NSString *property4;
@end

@implementation AwesomeModel
- (NSArray *)ignoreProperties {
    return @[@"property3"];
}
@end

// --- serializer
AwesomeModel *obj = [AwesomeModel new];
NSArray *blackList = [obj ignoreProperties]; // only returns "property3"
```

Obviously above code doesn't work but how can I implement `ignoreProperties` so, that it would return `property1` and `property3`?

Very bad way:

```
@implementation AwesomeModel
- (NSArray *)ignoreProperties {
    return [[super ignoreProperties] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@"property3"]];
}
@end
```

A lot of potential for bugs. If a subclass forgets about invoking `super` the chain would be broken. Or `BaseModel` return `nil` then the code wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Why could not you keep your `ignoreProperties` array getter method untouched and just put into your `BaseModel` `init` - `self.ignoreProperties = @[@"property1"]` and in your AwesomeModel init after `self=[super init];` - `[self.ignoreProperties addObject: @"property3"]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think teamnorge is on the right track His code won't work as posted, though, since the array isn't mutable.

Make your property a mutable array. Have the base class create it it init's init method:

In your base class header:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ignoreProperties;
```

Then in the init for your base class:

```
-(instanceType) init;
{
  self = [super init];
  if (!self)
    return nil;
  self.ignoreProperties =  [@[@"property1"] mutableCopy];
}
```

And in the init for your subclass:

```
-(instanceType) init;
{
  self = [super init];
  if (!self)
    return nil;
  [self.ignoreProperties  addObject: @"property2"];
  //or to add multiple objects...
  NSArray *newProperties = @[@"property2", @"property3"];
  [self.ignoreProperties  addObjectsFromArray: newProperties];
}
```

For efficiency's sake, it might be better to make the array immutable and have the subclass's init method replace it with a an array created using `arrayByAddingObject` or `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray`. (Immutable objects are less costly for the system than their mutable forms. In this case the array of properties will only be created once at initialization of your class, and then persist for it's lifetime.)

Comment: I don't want to create it in the init method. This approach is the same bad approach as I have pointed out before. Each and every subclass would need to implement the same code (`addObjectsFromArray:`). If some subclass just assigns it instead of adding, the chain would be broken. Subclasses should just be descriptive (= just tell the serializer that there are some properties to ignore). I just want to implement the code to combine all arrays once. Models shouldn't be bothered to implement such code.

Comment: Ok, then create a read-only array property in the base class. Create a method that can be used to add properties. Have the method use a private variable of the base class. Subclasses can call either of the methods (read the properties or add properties) but not access the instance variable.

Comment: another solution I came up is to make `ignoreProperties` a class method. then the serializer can loop through the class inheritance hierarchy using `superclass` and invoke those class methods to add them all together. It would solve the problem but I'm not sure if class methods are the perfect solution for it.